# How to test multiple testValues with True or False behind it

Tags: java, junit

I want that the method public void testinputBiggerThan() is performed with all testvalue in the method public static Collection testValues().

So I want to give multiple parameters with a true or false condition of that testValue and than this been evaluated inside `AssertTrue`

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParamaterizedTest {


  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection testValues() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { 18.5, true },
        { 16.5, false },
        { 19.5, true },
        { 15.5, false },
        { 20.5, true }
    });
  }

  @Test
  public void testinputBiggerThanExpected(){
    Double expected = 17.5;
    AssertTrue(expected < //how do I get here all the values testValues() and evaluated whether this is the case 18.5 is (true because 18.5 is bigger than 17.5)& true in testValues()=true, etc );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first migrate to JUnit5. Your test method `testinputBiggerThanExpected` should use `@ParameterizedTest` annotation instead of `@Test`. Read this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/parameterized-tests-junit-5).

```
public class ParamaterizedTest {

  public static Collection testValues() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { 18.5, true },
        { 16.5, false },
        { 19.5, true },
        { 15.5, false },
        { 20.5, true }
    });
  }

  @ParameterizedTest
  @MethodSource("testValues")
  public void testinputBiggerThanExpected(float floatValue, boolean booleanValue){
    Double expected = 17.5;
    assertTrue(expected < floatValue);
  }
}
```

or a more simple approach:

```
public class ParamaterizedTest {

  @ParameterizedTest
  @ValueSource(floats = { 18.5, 16.5, 19.5, 15.5, 20.5 })
  public void testinputBiggerThanExpected(float floatValue) {
    Double expected = 17.5;
    assertTrue(expected < floatValue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer uses the JUnit 5 way of parameterized tests, but the question uses the JUnit 4 way of parameterized test. Unless the OP is willing to switch to JUnit 5, this will not work for them. I would also highly recommend that you point this out explicitly in your answer, otherwise it is just confusing.

Comment: When I execute the fist code code example I receive the error `org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert object of type java.lang.Double to type java.lang.Float`

Comment: I changed it `testinputBiggerThanExpected(double floatValue` However the test cases fail, at test case 16.5 and 15.5. Because 15.5 and 16.5 is smaller than 17.5 and both 16.5 and 15.5 have false behind it, so if false (because it's smaller) and false (because behind 16.5, there is false) and false false is true: this case should be evaluated true and all the five testcases should pass

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a constructor with the right amount and types of parameters as returned by your `testValues()` method, then you assign the values as fields and use those fields in your test.

For each set of values returned by the `@Parameterized.Parameters` method, and each `@Test` annotated method, the `Parameterized` test runner will create a new instance of your test class, with the set of  values, and the run the test method (this means that if you have 5 sets of values and 3 test-methods, it will create 5 * 3 instances of your test class).

So, change your code to:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class ParamaterizedTest {

  private final double testDouble;
  private final boolean expectedResult;

  public ParameterizedTest(double testDouble, boolean expectedResult) {
    this.testDouble = testDouble;
    this.expectedResult = expectedResult;
  }

  @Parameterized.Parameters
  public static Collection testValues() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
        { 18.5, true },
        { 16.5, false },
        { 19.5, true },
        { 15.5, false },
        { 20.5, true }
    });
  }

  @Test
  public void testinputBiggerThanExpected(){
    Double expected = 17.5;
    assertEquals(expectedResult, expected < testDouble);
  }
}
```

See also the JUnit 4 documentation on [Parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests).

As an aside, you're currently using JUnit 4, and the way of using parameterized tests in JUnit 5 is both simpler and more powerful. I recommend switching. See the JUnit 5 User Guide, section [Parameterized Tests](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parameterized-tests) for more information.